# Include a “From Name” when using GMailSender

Tags: java, android, email

I’m trying to send emails from within my app using GMailSender. I want the emails to have a proper “From Name”, you know like “Service Name <email@service.com>”. However, using this syntax still strips off the Name and I just see the email address. I’ve tried searching all over, as well as trying out various combinations to get it to work. Without avail. Here’s my code for your reference:

```
GMailSender SenderEmail = new GMailSender("email@service.com", "password");
try {
    String Subject = "Subject";
    String Body = "Body";
    String FromEmailID = "Service Name <email@service.com>";
    String ToEmailID = "user@gmail.com";
    SenderEmail.sendMail(Subject,Body,FromEmailID,ToEmailID);

    startActivity(new Intent(OneActivity.this, TwoActivity.class));
    finish();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that from the API. You need to set your display name from the Gmail interface itself.

[see this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158?hl=en)

Comment: @adrian-vegas thanks for your response. But the display name is already setup in the Gmail account. Yet I see only the email address.